# Nib loading creates wrong frame size

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to create an overlay that asks for the user's email, and I designed it using a nib, with its own custom UIView class. The overridden instantiation method loods like this

```
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame: frame];
    if (self)
    {
        self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EmailOverlayView" owner: self options: nil] firstObject];
    }

    return self;
}
```

But whenever I try to instantiate the view within the view controller (these are all nib loaded as well, no storyboards) no matter what values for the width and height I put in, the view completely ignores them and either puts in 600x600 if I use size classes, or the incorrect frame sizes if I don't use size classes, which is incredibly aggravating. I created the view in viewDidAppear and logged out the values to illustrate what I mean.

```
NSLog(@"%f, %f", self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height); --> 320.000000, 519.000000
CPREmailOverlayView *overlay = [[CPREmailOverlayView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)]; 
[overlay layoutIfNeeded];
NSLog(@"%f, %f", overlay.frame.size.width, overlay.frame.size.height); --> 320.000000, 568.000000
[self.view addSubview: overlay];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront: overlay];
```

It's incredibly aggravating that you create a view using specific values, then the system changes them behind your back, so any help would be greatly appreciated as I would rather not create all these views programmatically.

Comment: Are you using auto-layout ?

Comment: Yeah I am, on both the nib and the view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code like this :

```
[overlay setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview: overlay];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront: overlay];
[self activateConstraintsForView:overlay respectToParentView:self.view];

- (void)activateConstraintsForView:(UIView *)view respectToParentView:(UIView *)parentView
{
    NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:parentView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                                     constant:0];

    NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:parentView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:0];

    NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:parentView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                   constant:0];

    NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                      toItem:parentView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                                    constant:0];

    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:topConstraint, leftConstraint, bottomConstraint, rightConstraint, nil]] ;
}
```

This code will make, your overlay.frame = self.view.frame.
Modify constants of constraint, to get your desired width and height.
Hope, it helps. Thank You. :)

Comment: Wow that worked perfectly! Thank you so much, I wish I could upvote you but I don't have enough reputation. What exactly is this code doing though...why does it work?

Comment: Function above activateConstraintsForView:respectToParentView: adds Auto-layout constraints programmatically, saying subview.frame must be equal to its parentView.frame. Reason you were not able to get your desired frame was, use of 'Auto-layout'. Since, you are adding your view programmatically you also need to give it constraint programmatically. Get a detail study of Autolayout to understand above code perfectly :)

Comment: Interesting, yeah I need to brush up on the programmatic aspects of auto-layout. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to custom UIView loaded from Xibs the following works for me;

```
+ (id)view{
    NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yourXibName" owner:self options:nil];
    return (yourClassName *)[nibs objectAtIndex:0];
}

Class *view = [Class view];
```

Then you can set the frame

```
view.frame = self.view.frame;
```

Comment: The only difference I see is that the frame is set after loading the xib